# Did Mathematica 9 remove some previously available stylesheets?

Tags: stylesheet

Did Mathematica 9 remove some previously available stylesheets? If so, how can I customize a currently available style sheet to be like a previous one or get previous version's stylesheet back? I frequently used the natural beige color stylesheet (Format > StyleSheet > Creative > NaturalColor), but Mathematica 9 seemed to have removed it.

Also, how do I check which stylesheet is currently employed?

Comment: The stylesheet being currently used by a notebook has a checkmark int Format > Stylesheet menu.

Comment: Doesn't work for me with a CDF document...

Answer (score 11):

As Brett Champion says in his answer the NaturalColor stylesheet is still availble but hidden. If you want to use it on a regular basis, I suggest moving a copy of it to a folder where *Mathematica* will find and put it on the Format > Stylesheet menu.

*Mathematica* can aid you in finding the stylesheet folders and the stylesheets themselves. The function

```
findStyleSheetFolders[] := 
   Module[{userStylesheetFolder, wolframStylesheetFolder}, 
     userStylesheetFolder = 
       FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd",  "StyleSheets"}]; 
     wolframStylesheetFolder = 
        FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "StyleSheets"}];
     {userStylesheetFolder, wolframStylesheetFolder}]
```

will find the required folders. `wolframStylesheetFolder` is where WRI installs the stylesheets WRI distributes with *Mathematica*. `userStylesheetFolder` is a good place to install a copy of the `NaturalColor.nb` stylesheet you use so it will appear on the stylesheet menu.

The function

```
findStyleSheets[] :=  FileNames["*.nb", findStyleSheetFolders[], ∞]
```

will show you all the stylesheets installed on your system.

On my system, evaluating

```
findStyleSheets[] // TableForm
```

gives

> /Applications/Mathematica.app/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/ArticleClassic.nb
>   /Applications/Mathematica.app/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/Article/JournalArticle.nb
>   /Applications/Mathematica.app/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/Article/LaTeX-Article.nb
>   /Applications/Mathematica.app/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/Article/LaTeX-Report.nb
>   /Applications/Mathematica.app/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/ArticleModern.nb
>   /Applications/Mathematica.app/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/Article/Preprint.nb
>   /Applications/Mathematica.app/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/Book/Compilation.nb
>   /Applications/Mathematica.app/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/Book/LaTeX-Book.nb
>   /Applications/Mathematica.app/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/Book/Monograph.nb
>   /Applications/Mathematica.app/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/Book/Textbook.nb
>
> ...
>
> /Applications/Mathematica.app/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/Creative/NaturalColor.nb
>   ...
>
> /Applications/Mathematica.app/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/Wolfram/Reference-zh.nb
>   /Users/oldmg/Library/Mathematica/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/Notebook.nb
>   /Users/oldmg/Library/Mathematica/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/OReilly.nb

As you see, I've installed two custom stylesheet notebooks in the user stylesheets folder. These custom stylesheets show up in my Format > Stylesheet menu. If you move a copy of `NaturalColor.nb` into your user stylesheets folder, it will be visible in your Format > Stylesheet menu.

Comment: I did what m_goldberg say but it didn't work for me. I worked it out as this: `Format->StyleSheet->Other` and choose `PastelColor.nb` file. `Then Format->Edit StyleSheet` and then pPush Install StyleSheet button.

Comment: On ver.10, the method proposed by m_goldberg doesn't work,that of @nadapez doesn't either. How to fix that problem?

Answer (score 10):

I liked that stylesheet (**Creative > Natural Color**) as well.

They're still present for backward compatibility, but are not listed in the **Format** menu anymore.  You should still be able to browse to them using **Stylesheet > Other...** or by modifying an existing notebook that uses the stylesheet.

Comment: On my Mac, they're at "/Applications/Mathematica.app/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/Creative/"

Comment: @cormullion I found them at "/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets" (v11.3 on a Mac)

Comment: At some point we had to move everything into the Contents directory when macOS became more strict about the structure of things inside the app bundle.  In general the stylesheets directory is `FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd",  "StyleSheets"}]`.