# naturalcolor stylesheet not working between linux and windows

Tags: stylesheet

I have encountered a weird problem with Mathematica 9. I have it installed on my laptop running Windows 7 and on my work computer now running Debian Wheezy. I am also using dropbox to access my work files and folders on the two systems. On both windows and linux I have setup the NaturalColour stylesheet as my default stylesheet for mathematica. I had no problems with this system until a few weeks ago when every time I open in linux a notebook written in windows, mathematica starts with that beep and the window with the error about the file could not be found. When I press OK on that window, the notebook opens in a new notebook with a really basic stylesheet: no title, subtitle and cell groups.

Any help would be great!

Update:

Output of the function in the suggested post:

/home/lucian/.Mathematica/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/NaturalColor.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/ArticleClassic.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/Article/JournalArticle.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/Article/LaTeX-Article.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/Article/LaTeX-Report.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/ArticleModern.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/Article/Preprint.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/Book/Compilation.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/Book/LaTeX-Book.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/Book/Monograph.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/Book/Textbook.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/Classic.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/Classroom.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/Core.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/Creative/NaturalColor.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/Creative/PastelColor.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/Creative/PrimaryColor.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/Default_8.0.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/Default.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/Demo.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/DemoText.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/Dialog.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/EnvironmentMenuClear.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/HelpBrowser.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/HTML.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/InlineModifier.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/NaturalColor.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/NotepadMono.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/Notepad.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/Package.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/Palette.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/PastelColor.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/PrimaryColor.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/PublicationDefault.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/Report/AutomatedReport.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/Report/ConfidentialReport.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/Report.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/Report/StandardReport.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/SlideShow/Earth.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/SlideShow/Garnet.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/SlideShow/Opal.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/SlideShow/Sapphire.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/SlideShow/Steel.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/SlideShow/Sunrise.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/SlideShow/Water.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/StyleMenuClear.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/StylesheetFormatting.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/SystemDialog.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/SystemPalette.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/Textbook.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/TutorialBook.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/Utility/Correspondence.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/Utility/Memo.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/Utility/Notepad.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/Utility/Outline.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/Wolfram/Demonstration.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/Wolfram/HandsOn.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/Wolfram/Legacy/Reference-v8-ja.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/Wolfram/Legacy/Reference-v8.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/Wolfram/Legacy/Reference-v8-zh.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/Wolfram/Reference-2.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/Wolfram/Reference-ja.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/Wolfram/Reference.nb,
/home/programs/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/Wolfram/Reference-zh.nb

I am sorry about the non-formatted text but I have no idea how to format an entire block of pasted text to make it look pretty here.

Comment: Your problem seems strongly related with this answer: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17323/did-mathematica-9-remove-some-previously-available-stylesheets?rq=1 The answer should provide code for detection and repair of the issue

Comment: Can we hear from the OP whether or not @hieron's comment was useful?  It's not obvious to me that the linked question is a duplicate since the OP states that everything was working until one day it wasn't.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed answer but I had to leave the office early yesterday. I have tried to use the information from the post suggested by @hieron but unfortunately it didn't work (of maybe I didn't do it right). I have copied the NaturalColour.nb stylesheet to the /home/username/.Mathematica stylesheet folder but the problem persists. So I don't think the problems are related. I could post the output of the function from hieron's post, if that helps anyone.

Comment: Post anything you can. I'm afraid that just these few lines are not helpful :)

Comment: I have updated the original post to include the output of the function from the post suggested by @hieron

Comment: It seems that nobody stumbled on this problem and I can't figure out how to solve it.

Comment: I managed to fix this problem (get around it rather!) by resetting my notebook to the default style sheet in windows and save the notebook. Then I opened it in Linux which worked correctly and there I switched to the NaturalColor style sheet. Saved again then opened in windows. Worked fine, except for an error that the NaturalColour.nb could not be found at the path that is saved in the linux version. Therefore I think a more permanent fix would be to copy the stylesheet file in the notebook dir. This way, windows and linux will be searching in the same path.

Answer (score 2):

It took me a long time but I have finally managed to find a good solution for my problem. I will try to explain it here in case someone else is looking for the same thing.

As I have stated in my question, I am using Mathematica on two computers, one running Linux and the other Windows 7. I also like to use the *NaturalColor.nb* stylesheet under ..\SystemFiles\FrontEnd\StyleSheets\Creative\ (this path is for Windows). When I was switching from one OS to the other I would get and annoying error that the stylesheet could not be found.

My solution is as follows:
On both systems copy the NaturalColor.nb file in the local configuration directory for each OS:

Windows 7:
c:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\SystemFiles\FrontEnd\StyleSheets\

Linux: /home/username/.Mathematica/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/

After this it is a matter of modifying the Global Preferences on each system. In particular, the following two fields need to be changed:

**StyleSheetPath**:

{ParentList,FrontEnd`FileName[{$UserBaseDirectory,"SystemFiles","FrontEnd","StyleSheets"},"PacletManager"->True]}

And

**DefaultStyleDefinitions**: "NaturalColor.nb"

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution.